# How to use MS Graph API and Python to add a client secret to AAD application

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for Python examples that use the MS Graph API, to generate a new client secret for a Microsoft Azure AD app registration. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You haven't done anything for someone to help you *with*.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [documentation for MS Graph?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: yes, I got this api call working through Postman. It is just I was looking to see if someone has done it through python already and can get a reference.

Comment: It's not possible to "reset", edit, or retrieve a secret's value once it's been added. You can only create a new secret

Comment: @scottwtang Yes, you are right. When I ran curl calls through postman, I could see the old secret and new secret. So rephrasing my question - I am looking for python implementations that actually generate new secret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example, along with obtaining a token using a client and secret

See the documentation for the [addPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API

**Obtain a bearer (and access) token**

```
# The App Registration's application (client) ID
client_id = ""

# Client secret created under App Registration blade
client_secret = ""

# Your Azure AD tenant ID
tenant_id = ""

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id         = client_id,
    client_credential = client_secret,
    authority         = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}")

scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

# Obtain bearer token from MS Graph
token = None
token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes = scopes)
```

**Add a new client secret using Graph API**

```
# The App Registration's object ID
app_object_id = ""    

req_uri = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{app_object_id}/addPassword"

req_headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token['access_token'],
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

req_body = json.dumps(
    {
        "passwordCredential": {
            "displayName": "Secret Description"
        }
    }
)

result = requests.post(url = req_uri, headers = req_headers, data = req_body)
```

Comment: I am getting below error ```NameError: name 'msal' is not defined```. I have used from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication.

Comment: @user312307 Either change the 1st line to `app = ConfidentialClientApplication(`, or change your import statement to just `import msal`. The way you call your methods is dependent on how you import your modules

Comment: Thanks @scottwtang. It worked, but will it be 'access_token' for Authorization? I am getting KeyError: 'access_token' for this line -     "Authorization": "Bearer " + token['access_token']. I believe this is to generate the access token before I call addPassword api

Comment: @user312307 That line is to form the HTTP request header used in the API call. The access token is already provided as part of the bearer token obtained in `line 9`. A `KeyError` exception means that the dictionary key (`access_token`) doesn't exist in the referenced dictionary (the results stored in the `token` variable is the dictionary).

Comment: I tried printing app results and I see this ```'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': "AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '1234566' was not found in the directory 'abc'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.``` I have passed the secret id in line 2 and secret value in line 3 and the tenant_id in line 4. I have verified from console - everything looks correct. Can you please let me know issue?

Comment: @user312307 If the issue was with the `client secret`, or `tenant ID`, you would get a different error, so we can assume the issue is with your `client ID`. This should be the ID labelled as `Application (client) ID` of the `App Registration`, not the `Enterprise Application` and not the `Object ID`

Comment: Thank you, Issue is fixed and I could see the token. Amazing. Is app_id  also the Application (client) ID ? or something else? As I see 404 when I print result now ```result = requests.post(url = req_uri, headers = req_headers, data = req_body)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244860/discussion-between-user312307-and-scottwtang).